# Embroider:MacrosConfig the given config from 'Project Path' for packageName 'undefined' is not JSON serializable

Tags: ember.js

When I try to start Ember server (`ember serve`) I get this error

[Embroider:MacrosConfig] the given config from 'C:\WebDev\cpc\front-end_service\node_modules\ember-get-config' for packageName 'undefined' is not JSON serializable.

Here's the stack error details ;

```
=================================================================================
    
    ENV Summary:
    
      TIME: Sat Apr 09 2022 01:13:15 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)
      TITLE: ember
      ARGV:
      - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
      - C:\Users\zak\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\bin\ember
      - s
      EXEC_PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
      TMPDIR: C:\Users\zak\AppData\Local\Temp
      SHELL: null
      PATH:
      - C
      - \Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C
      - \Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C
      - \Windows\system32;C
      - \Windows;C
      - \Windows\System32\Wbem;C
      - \Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C
      - \Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C
      - \Program Files\Git\cmd;C
      - \Program Files\dotnet\;C
      - \Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C
      - \Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C
      - \Program Files\nodejs\;C
      - \Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C
      - \Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C
      - \Program Files\PuTTY\;C
      - \Users\zak\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C
      - \Users\zak\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C
      - \Users\zak\AppData\Roaming\npm
      PLATFORM: win32 x64
      FREEMEM: 4299919360
      TOTALMEM: 12786380800
      UPTIME: 60966
      LOADAVG: 0,0,0
      CPUS:
      - Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz - 2195
      - Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz - 2195
      - Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz - 2195
      - Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz - 2195
      - Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz - 2195
      - Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz - 2195
      - Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz - 2195
      - Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz - 2195
      ENDIANNESS: LE
      VERSIONS:
      - ares: 1.17.1
      - brotli: 1.0.9
      - cldr: 39.0
      - icu: 69.1
      - llhttp: 2.1.3
      - modules: 83
      - napi: 8
      - nghttp2: 1.42.0
      - node: 14.17.3
      - openssl: 1.1.1k
      - tz: 2021a
      - unicode: 13.0
      - uv: 1.41.0
      - v8: 8.4.371.23-node.67
      - zlib: 1.2.11
    
    ERROR Summary:
    
      - broccoliBuilderErrorStack: [undefined]
      - code: [undefined]
      - codeFrame: [undefined]
      - errorMessage: [Embroider:MacrosConfig] the given config from 'projectPath\node_modules\ember-get-config' for packageName 'undefined' is not JSON serializable.
      - errorType: [undefined]
      - location:
        - column: [undefined]
        - file: [undefined]
        - line: [undefined]
      - message: [Embroider:MacrosConfig] the given config from 'projectPath\node_modules\ember-get-config' for packageName 'undefined' is not JSON serializable.
      - name: Error
      - nodeAnnotation: [undefined]
      - nodeName: [undefined]
      - originalErrorMessage: [undefined]
      - stack: Error: [Embroider:MacrosConfig] the given config from 'projectPath\node_modules\ember-get-config' for packageName 'undefined' is not JSON serializable.
        at MacrosConfig.internalSetConfig (projectPath\node_modules\@embroider\macros\src\macros-config.js:163:19)
        at MacrosConfig.setOwnConfig (projectPath\node_modules\@embroider\macros\src\macros-config.js:142:21)
        at Class.included (projectPath\node_modules\@embroider\macros\src\ember-addon-main.js:25:26)
        at Class.superWrapper [as included] (projectPath\node_modules\core-object\lib\assign-properties.js:34:20)
        at projectPath\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\addon.js:497:26
        at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
        at Class.eachAddonInvoke (projectPath\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\addon.js:494:24)
        at Class.included (projectPath\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\addon.js:769:10)
        at Class.superWrapper [as included] (projectPath\node_modules\core-object\lib\assign-properties.js:34:20)
        at Class.included (projectPath\node_modules\ember-get-config\index.js:29:26)
    
    =================================================================================
```

I searched a lot on Google but I didn't find any solution
If someone can help, thanks.

Comment: if you use vscode, open the javascript debugger terminal, and then run ember serve, can you pause on this exception? I want to know what package it's trying to look at, and what is going on with the config for the package it's trying to read. The error is telling me that someone is using a non-serializable config in their config for whatever this addon is -- so we gotta find out what's going on there.

Comment: also, this is a good issue to report here as well: https://github.com/embroider-build/embroider/issues

because the error is thrown from `@embroider/macros`, yet the error is not helpful enough to debug (without actually using a debugger), so the bug would be that the error needs to have more information and provide actionable info.

Comment: I switched from Windows to Ubuntu,  all works fine, maybe the issue with the Windows 10 access authorization.

Comment: could be! Windows is whole 'nother beast